# Symfony2 - Problems with mapping object in field form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

`Objective` has one `Perspective`

```
class Objective{
    ...
    public function setPerspective(\Cboujon\BSCBundle\Entity\Pespective $perspective = null)
    {
        $this->perspective = $perspective;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Objective.orm.yml**

```
Cboujon\BSCBundle\Entity\Objective:
manyToOne:
        perspective:
            targetEntity: Perspective
            inversedBy: objectives
            joinColumn:
                name: perspective_id
                referencesColumn: id
```

**ObjectiveType.php**

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('perspective');
    }
```

Symfony2 renders a form with combobox with all perspectives. That is ok! butn when I submit the `create form` I get the error:

> ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Cboujon\BSCBundle\Entity\Objective::setPerspective() must be an
>   instance of Cboujon\BSCBundle\Entity\Pespective, instance of
>   Cboujon\BSCBundle\Entity\Perspective given, called in
>   /home/cristhian/php_apps/Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php
>   on line 376 and defined in
>   /home/cristhian/php_apps/Symfony/src/Cboujon/BSCBundle/Entity/Objective.php
>   line 63

Note: I also try:

```
        $builder->add('perspective', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'CboujonBSCBundle:Perspective',
                )
              )
    ;
```

But I get the same error.

Note2: If I remove `\Cboujon\BSCBundle\Entity\Pespective` from setPerspective definition I can submit the form OK.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iThere is a typo in your Entity setter when specifying the argument type:

```
public function setPerspective(\Cboujon\BSCBundle\Entity\Pespective $perspective = null)
{
    $this->perspective = $perspective;

    return $this;
}
```

Not \Cboujon\BSCBundle\Entity\ **Pespective**, but \Cboujon\BSCBundle\Entity\ **Perspective**